# QEMU "Permission denied"

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, qemu

Because I can't install WSL 2 because I have Windows 1909, I thought of an idea. How about I partition my disk, extract a live ISO (in this case ArchBang) on a separate partition from my OS, then include my OS disk in the VM and boot the VM from the partition? Unfortunately, this did not work. I tried to invoke `qemu-system-x86_64` with `-hda .` after `cd` to partition L:/ (what I extracted it onto). I went as far as to use a command line with Administrator Permissions, and look at the permissions I gave QEMU, before I realized there are obviously way smarter people out there than me.
After I hopefully can boot from that disk, my main goal is to include C:/ as a separate disk with read/write ability, so I can run Linux applications on Windows.
**Edit-** I have looked at QEMU's docs, and found what I think is issue. I was trying to access files that, to the machine, did not exist to it. However something strange comes up when using the HDD access syntax provided by QEMU (the //./L:/ syntax). It throws "Permission denied", an error that has a more restricting connotation to me. This is a definite error where the file was found, but deliberately not accessible to QEMU. It also means the issue for sure has something to do with Windows permissions.
*Sidenote-* There are two `windows` tags on this post, because I don't know if this is Windows 10 only. Also, please don't say "WSL 2 is available to Windows 1909 now". I a) want to have a GUI, b) want to learn about QEMU and Virtual Machines, and c) want to use ArchBang as my live distro, something WSL doesn't have. This is not a WSL question.

Comment: August 20 2020 - "WSL 2 Support is coming to Windows 10 Versions 1903 and 1909"  (Currently, only for x64 systems) - see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)

Comment: Yes I tried WSL2 with QEMU and it works. You have to be on Windows Insider 'Dev' channel afaik, but it might have reached Beta state. Beware there are other issues with the latest Dev WSL2 versions, particularly this issue is hair-pulling https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4731 and you can also run Linux applications via X11 forwarding even on WSL1 with stable windows it just requires a windows xserver like vcxsrv + `export DISPLAY=:0` for WSL1, in WSL2 the gotcha is you gotta have the right IP from `/etc/resolv.conf` and not use localhost as WSL2 is now a virtual adapter with own IP

Comment: I've been using VNC with WSL 1 and 2 for a long time now.